# Probability of rotation.

Tags: probability

6 random numbers are chosen in between 1 to 999 and then 3 are chosen from that 6 to be the sides of a brick and the remaining three be the sides of a box, what is the probability of the brick fully rotates inside the box?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: If the numbers are uniformly random reals in [0,1000], the probability is $\pi/120$.

Comment: @Magma - Would you mind sharing your answer, even though it only answers a variant of the OP question?  It's fascinating esp. given how fast you did it!

Comment: "fully rotates inside the box". Do you mean that you can rotate it about an axis parallel to one of the edges of the box? So if the box has sides $A<B<C$ and the brick has sides $a<b<c$ then we require $a^2+b^2\le A^2$ or $b^2+c^2\le B^2$

Comment: Or do you require rotation about any axis, so that $a^2+b^2+c^2<A^2$?

Comment: Well its about any axis, not the axises parallel to the edges, i mean not only about X Y and Z axis

Comment: @antkam Alright, I've written up what I did.

Answer (score 0):

Given a 6-tuple $(a,b,c,A,B,C)$, where $a,b,c$ are the side lengths of the brick and $A,B,C$ are the side lengths of the box, the brick can freely rotate inside the box if and only if $A, B, C$ are all not less than the main diagonal $D := \sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$ of the brick.

To answer the variation of the question I mentioned as a comment: Suppose $a,b,c,A,B,C$ are all independent and uniformly random in $[0,1000]$. To simplify, let's say the numbers are all uniform in $[0,1]$ instead. The probability will not change due to this (imagine that we just change our unit of length from millimetres to  metres).

Now the desired probability $P$ is equal to the volume of the set $$S: = \{(a,b,c,A,B,C) \in [0,1]^6 : \sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2} < \min(A,B,C)\}$$
divided by the volume of $[0,1]^6$ (which is $1$). To find that volume, we simply integrate $1$ over $S$. For that, let $V = \{(a,b,c )\in [0,1]^3 : a^2+b^2+c^2 < 1\}$, $A := \{(a,b,c) \in [0,1]^3 : a^2+b^2+c^2=1\}$ and $C_r := [r,1]^3$.

Now
$$P = \int_S 1 \,\mathrm{d}(a,b,c,A,B,C) = \iiint_V\iiint_{C_D}1\,\mathrm{d}(A,B,C)\,\mathrm{d}(a,b,c) = \iiint_V(1-D)^3\,\mathrm{d}(a,b,c)$$
Using the shell method, we can rewrite this as
$$P = \iint_A\int_{[0,1]} D^2(1-D)^3\,\mathrm{d}D\,\mathrm{d}s = \frac{\pi}{2}\int_{[0,1]} D^2(1-D)^3\,\mathrm{d}D = \frac{\pi}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{60} = \frac{\pi}{120}.$$